# How to set new attribute and sum the values of that attribute in input type checbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

In normal the `<input id="addfees" type="checkbox" name="rowid" value="feeid">` has some default attributes such as id, type, name, value.

In addition to that I need to pass a custom attribute say attribute name as `feeamount = "3000"` and I need the input as like `<input type="checkbox" id="addfees" name="rowid" feeamount = "3000" value="feeid">`

Here I have added feeamount as custom attribute, and also I need to sum up this feeamount because there will be multiple rows with checkbox and when user clicks each checkbox the feeamount attribute of that checkbox needs to get added and the final sum amount should be resulted.

And I need to have value attribute with feeid only.

The checkbox I tried with is,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees" name="rowid" data-feeamount = "3000" value="feeid">
```

The JavaScript I tried with is,

```
var value = $("#addfees").data('fee-amount');
console.log(value);
```

But I think it's a wrong way to approach this problem. How can I set a new custom attribute, and sum that attribute?

Comment: I'm kinda unsure what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using multiple checkbox, then you can use jQuery `each()` method to get this. check updated snippet below..

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
   var sum = 0;
   $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += $(this).data('feeamount');
   })
   $('#output').text(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees1" name="rowid1" data-feeamount = "3000" value="feeid">
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees2" name="rowid2" data-feeamount = "1000" value="feeid">
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees3" name="rowid3" data-feeamount = "2000" value="feeid">
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees4" name="rowid4" data-feeamount = "5000" value="feeid">
<input type="checkbox" id="addfees5" name="rowid5" data-feeamount = "2000" value="feeid"><br \>
Result: <span id="output">0</span>
```